# Create a Download button to download file from Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-storage

I am building my app using nextjs. I want to create a downloaded button to download file from firebase but it often give me weird output.

I am using saveAs (file-saver) as example below (it is same as if I use fetch or use official firebase example)

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    saveAs("the_getDownloadURL(storage_path)", "example.jpg")
  }}
  >
  Download Image
</button>
```

It give me this error in my console with http 400 error:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/.....5wDsku4DGiK8q.jpg?alt=media&token=xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx
```

[image]

and then it open the file in a new tab, I like to know how to let my user click the button and download it directly

I am following this tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files and also tried using saveAs from "file-saver", would like to know how to resolve the problem of let my user click the button and download file consistently

Comment: What error does it show in network logs response?

Comment: the GET return 400 bad request, don't have much additional info on it ... I been searching around stackoverflow of this .... but this error seems getting away ....